# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (every where it is opening)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Hi i have developed an online examination for one of my client. It has completed but there is an issue which is giving me too much trouble. When anyone starts the test and crosses some questions, suddenly webpage got refreshed and an error named ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE occurs. "This page isn’t working
www.vidyapro.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" . i am attaching a screenshot as well. This is coded on php with mysql and i am using linux hosting.
 The url is 
https://www.vidyapro.com/ca-cpt/mocktrial.php?n=1.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with another browser? I don't think this is an issue from your server side.

Comment: It is working for me when I click an answer and 'next'. I don't see any errors. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Looks to be a Chrome error.. i have a feeling something is wrong with the ssl certificate.. Also IE11 gives a error.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that something is spamming the heck out of `ajax.php?action=get_info`.

Comment: true @aynber a interval off 500 ms might be a bit to short..  shivaji kumar you should update the items with a `red dot` classes on the ajax event basically when pressing the next button and remove the setInterval spam events

Comment: Hi guys Thanks for your quick response, when i am trying with firefox some other error is occuring. Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to www.vidyapro.com.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: Thanks @raymondnijland let me check it. will get back to you.

Comment: check your brawsers and windows, probably you have some extension or plugin is installed that is messing it up

Comment: @AhmedSunny Its coming everywhere, not only in my computer.

Comment: "when i am trying with firefox some other error is occuring. Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to www.vidyapro.com. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem" Yes i have a feeling your ssl certificate is wrong you might want to invest more in a better one from better SSL certificate providers

Comment: you are sending request in loop, and your server cannot manage, and when you click next or anyother action, sometime the request is success and sometime fails, get_info is the request

Comment: @RaymondNijland i also thinks that there is some issue with ssl because when i am uploading same code on another hosting with other domain without SSL. Its working fine.
http://www.brandingheighttechnologies.com/clients/vidyapro/mocktrial.php?n=1 this is the url

Comment: Yes what @AhmedSunny said also makes sense the other hoster could have other firewall rules allowing more traffic from the same IP in less time..

Comment: both hosting are from godaddy with the same plan.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is your Javascript is going crazy! Requests being sent all the time, with no headers and no response!

[image: Network Panel]

Why does it need to do that? Surely it should only trigger when you submit your next answer.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, let me check it.

Comment: yes i think this is causing issue, i also got this error www.vidyapro.com took too long to respond.

Comment: Yes, that will be the 503 responses you see there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503